# android firebase saving data to realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In android app I create a firebase user authenticated by phone number and it works fine then I update this user adding display name and this is fine too; in the end I want to save user's data into firebase database so I wrote this rule:

```
"users" : {
  "$user_id" : {   // firebase user uid
    ".read"  : "$user_id === auth.uid",
    ".write" : "$user_id === auth.uid",

    ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['enabled', 'group', 'name'])",

    "enabled" : { ".validate" : "newData.isBoolean()" },
    "group"   : { ".validate" : "newData.isString()" },
    "name"    : { ".validate" : "newData.isString()" },
  }
}
```

This doesn't work and I get returned "permission denied" altough the simulator shows everything is fine (in the simulation I use custom authentication and set firebase as provider with the user's uid).

the user's class is:

```
public class User {
    public boolean enabled;
    public String group;
    public String name;

    public User() { }

    public User(boolean enabled, String group, String name) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.group = group;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and i try to save it by:

```
private void saveUserToDB() {
    User newUser = new User(true, "operators", currentUser.getDisplayName());
    mRootRef.child("users").child(currentUser.getUid()).setValue(newUser, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
            if (databaseError != null) {
                Log.e("ERROR", "Data could not be saved " + databaseError.getMessage());
            } else {
                Log.e("SUCCESS", "Data saved successfully.");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Can anybody kindly help me to understand why this happens?
Thanks

**UPDATE**
below is a "schema" of how the database should be:

```
{
    "messages" : {
        "1763409620982" : { // timestamp
            "position" : "position text",
            "sender"   : "sender name",
            "text"     : "message text"
        },
        "1763409734527" : { // timestamp
            "position" : "position text",
            "sender"   : "sender name",
            "text"     : "message text"
        }

        ...
    },

    "users" : {
        "Yi79w0HgA4ZTNAMHadixzoO5PaR2" : { // firebase user uid
            "enabled" : true,
            "group"   : "group 1",
            "name"    : "user display name"
        },
        "kX22c0GgL4ZTNAMHallfgoO4pBN1" : { // firebase user uid
            "enabled" : true,
            "group"   : "group 2",
            "name"    : "user name"
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

and here's the full set of rules:

```
{
    "rules": {

        "messages" : {
            ".read"    : "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('group').val() === 'group 1'",
            ".write"   : "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('group').val() === 'group 2'",

            "$tstamp" :{

                ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['position', 'sender', 'text'])",

                "position"  : { ".validate" : "newData.isString()" },
                "sender"    : { ".validate" : "newData.isString()" },
                "text"      : { ".validate" : "newData.isString()" },
            } 
        },

        "users" : {
            "$user_id" : {
                ".read"  : "$user_id === auth.uid",
                ".write" : "$user_id === auth.uid",

                ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['enabled', 'group', 'name'])",

                "enabled" : { ".validate" : "newData.isBoolean()" },
                "group"   : { ".validate" : "newData.isString()" },
                "name"    : { ".validate" : "newData.isString()" },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

as to the class *user* it's defined as above and only used into the method *saveUserToDB*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add push() before setValue(): It will add new sub-node containing all the fields from object of User class:

```
mRootRef.child("users").child(currentUser.getUid()).push().setValue(and so on...
```

Comment: Can you please share snapshot of your DB structure, and also implementation of the class User? Thanks!

Comment: r08y, not sure this is only reason, but User class is missing getters and setters. Please make them and make sure they are public. Same about Message. One more tip - before you setting hard rules (especially validation) - try at the beginning to run without them, and  see what you get.

Comment: Well Cadet, I don't think classes are the problem because according to [firebase documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) the they're ok.
As to making loose rules in the beginning, well I get _"permission denied"_ even if I set **auth != null** or **true** for read/write, which is very strange.
It seems is like I'm trying to save to a different project/database for which user doesn't have authorization; I also check the **google-services.json** and it seems ok.

Comment: r08y, according to the firebase documents you provided:

"Pass a custom Java object, if the class that defines it has a default constructor that takes no arguments and has public getters for the properties to be assigned." 

But - your class is missing getters....

Comment: my fault Cadet, I've been very blind and careless in reading that one.
Thank you

Comment: That's fine)) For this we are here trying to help each other.
Finally, the issue was resolved?

Comment: Yes Cadet, as I said I was careless in reading that Firebase doc and you shed a light on it, thanks again.

Comment: If answer is helpful - you are welcome to vote on it )))

Answer (score 0):

May be you need write permission?:
[image: Firebase rules]

Comment: But in the rules it's already stated that each user can read and write it's own data, why I should add one more write permission?

Comment: Usually when I search permission denied reason, I allow everything and then return back permissions one by one.

Comment: no way nikolai and you know strangely I get "permission denied" even if I set _".write": "auth.uid != null"_ when it's supposed that everybody can write